# using string index for array avoids type safety?

Tags: typescript

I'm just learning typescript, and I noticed it doesn't have type safety for arrays when indexing by strings.  It works as expected when indexing by number.  Anyone explain this?  I doubt its a bug but I can't find any information about this behavior.  Thanks

```
let x : string[] = [];
x[0] = 'test'; // OK, as expected
x[0] = 123; // as expected, error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
x['hi'] = 123; // OK??  Expected error TS2322 as above
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you *don't* have the `--noImplicitAny` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) turned on.

Turn it on and it will throw a compile error:

[image: error]

Comment: That option doesn't seem to cause TS2322 to show up, it seems to be a different check. What would happen if you try `x['hi'] = 'bar'`? Would it show up the same error as on your screenshot? If so, then it's a generic error/warning related to accessing an array with non-numeric index (~trying to use array as a hash) and completely not about a type mismatch between the array's element type `string` and assigning `123` -- and from what I understood the OP and TS2322 are about that.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl doing `x['hi'] = 'bar';` would be the same error. Also, yes, it's an error with `--noImplicitAny` because the object's type does not have an index signature defined with `[key: string]: number;`. Arrays have an index signature of `[key: number]: T;`... in this case `T` being `string`.